# How can I post JSON data in a way that results in a full page load?

Tags: json, forms, jquery

I can already use jQuery.post to send JSON data to the server, but I can't find a way to have the response replace my current page just as a regular old POST would when using plain HTML.

The only way I know right now to come close is to create a dummy form, add the JSON data as a value, then trigger submit. This seems like a big hack and also requires the server side to know where to look for this value (whereas it automatically detects JSON when jQuery sends it).

Please tell me there's a better way!

Example desired usage (note that I don't want the data encoded in the URL):

```
magic_load_page('/page', {'foo':'bar', 'list':[1,4,9,16]}); // uses POST request
```

Comment: Why would you not just post the page instead of using jquery?

Comment: the better way is to post the page without ajax. You still can preprocess the data (if any) with jquery

Comment: if you need to simply reload a page or load another one, you can do it via javascript. The server can reply with a url or a new page location, and all you need to do in your jQuery success handler is `window.location = <received url>`.

Comment: @Kory I access the data on both client and server side as JSON for consistency. Ideally I want to be able to post the data without even using a form in the first place.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz that's what I'm doing right now (preprocessing), but would like to avoid this step and post it directly if possible.